# Is there a way to list stopped EC2 instances using Boto3?

Tags: python, json, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have already tried using **describe_instance_status** method like in below. But it does not return any of the stopped EC2 instances. Apparently, it does not identify any stopped instances at all. Is it possible to use describe_instance_status method to list down all the stopped EC2 instances? Thanks! :)

```
response_one = ec2.describe_instance_status(Filters=[
    {
        'Name': 'instance-state-name',
        'Values': [
            'stopped',
            'running'
        ]
    },
],

)

print(response_one)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`describe_instances`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) instead

```py
response_one = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[
    {
        'Name': 'instance-state-name',
        'Values': [
            'stopped',
            'running'
        ]
    },
])

print(response_one)
```

and if you have a large number of instances, use the [paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Paginator.DescribeInstances)